# How to switch a single pole light to

Tags: electrical

I have 8 recessed can lights in the ceiling of my finished basement.  The lights are operated by one pole switch w/dimmer.  Is there any way to separate the can light in order to turn on one row at a time.  We found that it is not necessary to have all 8 can lights on at the same time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The system was designed with a different philosophy: rather than turn 4 lights off, dim all to 50%.  Now you want to reinvent that.  OK.

There are two ways I can think of.  One is to rewire the ceiling, which involves a lot of fishing, luck, and/or demolition and reconstruction of the finished ceiling.  You may need a bigger switch box to accommodate 2 switches, because I have not seen duplex dimmer switches meant to fit in a 1-gang box.

The other way is to use home-automation technology to make each lamp individually addressible.  Then use a smart switch for coarse control, or an "app" on a compatible smart device (iPod/iPhone/android) for very precise control (e.g. Lights 2, 7 and 8 on 40%, light 6 on 100%).  They don't like us to recommend particular brands or peoducts here since questions tend to be archived for a long time, but you'll find plenty on the market.

If you're swinging toward replacing with smart fixtures, think about also making the leap to LED.  They are finally market-ready with a good selection in color temp and CRI at a sane price, considering they will outlast the house.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have 8 lights controlled by one switch. Depend on how many lights in a row as you mentioned, it definitely needs more switches. It should be one switch/dimmer for each row. You need a lot of rewiring between the lights to the switch location. If you have already had wires pre-roughed in the ceiling to the switch location, it will be straight forward if you only need to rewiring the switch and lights. Otherwise, you need to open the ceiling and refinish it after all rewiring done.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other 2 answers explain your wiring options well. Although, if you want a super simple solution that gets you mostly what you want without rewiring. Then, just remove alternating of undesirable bulbs or, of course, unscrew them enough so they don't light.

No dimming to fool around with, no wasted energy & extra bulbs for the rest of the house if you find yourself out of bulbs. The reason for this option is because future owners may desire your single switch for all lights & wouldn't want a 2-switch box's ugliness.